# Is it possible to login in twitter within an iOS app and not use the twitter account that is stored in the settings of the device?

Tags: ios, twitter, authentication

I want to do this because I am building an app, which is going to be used within a campaign and many people will be asked to login in their twitter account, in the same device.

Comment: Yes, it is possible by using Twitter's own `OAuth`.

Comment: Here. Take a look : https://dev.twitter.com//

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874785/retrieving-twitter-oauth-token-using-social-framework-ios6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the default account of the iOS device, you can use Twitter's own `OAuth` tokens and then handle them independently in your application.

You can see the documentation at [Twitter's Developer Site](https://dev.twitter.com//)