# Retrieving Twitter OAuth Token using Social Framework and account frame work in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I  Had an application in which i am doing twitter login to access the users basic info.i am using social&account frame work.all working fine,

```
`if([self userHasAccessToTwitter])
        {
        ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
            if (granted) {
                NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                // Check if the users has setup at least one Twitter account
                if (accounts.count > 0)
                {
                    ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];
                    // Creating a request to get the info about a user on Twitter
                    SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:twitterAccount.username forKey:@"screen_name"]];
                    [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
                    // Making the request
                    [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            // Check if we reached the reate limit
                            if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                                NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
                                return;
                            }
                            // Check if there was an error
                            if (error) {
                                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                return;
                            }
                            // Check if there is some response data
                            if (responseData) {
                                NSError *error = nil;
                                NSArray *TWData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                                NSString *profileImageStringURL = [(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];

                                // Update the interface with the loaded data

                                [self getProfileImageForURLString:profileImageStringURL];
                            }
                        });
                    }];
                }
            }
`
```

But if he is not configured any accounts in the settings i need to do a custom login like in instagram,using xAuth login.Can anybody help me ,I had gone through this

> [Retrieving Twitter OAuth Token using Social Framework (iOS6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874785/retrieving-twitter-oauth-token-using-social-framework-ios6)

But nothing seems to be clear to me,how to make an SLrequest with username and password to access the auth token and make him to login to twitter is the pbm confusing me.can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: Check this post. http://natashatherobot.com/ios-twitter-login-parse/. Explains login with settings credentials and via Web